# Goのwebサーバの標準出力がコンテナのログ出力に反映されません

Tags: go, kubernetes

GoのWebサーバ（厳密にはlabstack/echo）を利用したアプリケーションをKubernetesのコンテナ上で実行しています。
アプリケーションにおいて、エラーが発生した場合、標準エラー出力にエラーの内容を出力しているのですが、`kubectl logs`コマンドにおいて出力を確認したところ、反映されませんでした。何故このような状況が発生するのでしょうか。

状況についての補足は下記の通りです。

- 起動時にはアプリケーションの標準出力を当該コマンドで確認できています。
- `exec`コマンドでPod内に入ると標準エラー出力を確認できています。
- `logs`コマンドをリアルタイムで監視している場合、Podの停止時に標準エラー出力が一度に表示されます。
- 該当の標準エラー出力に関するコードを下記の通り、変更したところ、反映されるようになりました。

```
// ■ 変更前
_, _ = os.Stderr.Write([]byte(formatNow + " " + id + " " + msg))
// ■ 変更後
output := fmt.Sprintf("%s\t%s\t%s\n  %+v\n", formatNow, id, msg)
_, _ = osStderr.Write([]byte(output))
```

Comment: 本来、stderr はバッファリングをしないのですが、[Kubernetes - Logging at the node level](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#logging-at-the-node-level) に、"Everything a containerized application writes to stdout and stderr is handled and redirected somewhere by a container engine." と書かれていて、Kubernetes の内部でバッファリングが行われている様です。これは推測になりますが、`kubectl logs` に `-f` オプション(`follow: Specify if the logs should be streamed`)をつければ表示される様になるかもしれません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

変更前はメッセージ末尾で改行していませんが、変更後は改行しています。このためどこかの IO バッファがフラッシュされるかどうかが変わっていそうです。

<sub>※この違いは、Twitter にて angel さんに[教えていただきました](https://twitter.com/angel_p_57/status/1243743348591955968)。</sub>

Comment: ご指摘頂いた通り、改行を行うことでフラッシュされたことを確認できました。
ありがとうございました。